# Reading files in parallel in python

Tags: python, file

I have a bunch of files (almost 100) which contain data of the format:
(number of people) \t (average age)

These files were generated from a random walk conducted on a population of a certain demographic. Each file has 100,000 lines, corresponding to the average age of populations of sizes from 1 to 100,000. Each file corresponds to a different locality in a third world country. We will be comparing these values to the average ages of similar sized localities in a developed country.

What I want to do is,

```
for each i (i ranges from 1 to 100,000):
  Read in the first 'i' values of average-age
  perform some statistics on these values
```

That means, for each run *i* (where *i* ranges from 1 to 100,000), read in the first *i* values of average-age, add them to a list and run a few tests (like Kolmogorov-Smirnov or chi-square)

---

In order to open all these files in parallel, I figured the best way would be a dictionary of file objects. But I am stuck in trying to do the above operations.

Is my method the best possible one (complexity-wise)?

Is there a better method?

Comment: "read the first *i* average-ages of all files (put them into a list or something"?  What does that mean?  Does it mean `for i in range(100): read i lines from the file`?  If so, please update your algorithm.

Comment: If the files are small you would add an overhead to access all of them at the same time because of GIL and the files are in the same harddisk

Comment: There are 100,000 lines in each file. I want to read the first i files for i ranging from 1 to 100,000

Comment: I don't think he's using the word "parallel" in the threading sense (Are you, Craig?).

Comment: This may not be the answer you're looking for, but this is the type of thing that relational databases were designed to answer. I would stand up a SQL DB of some sort, load everything in there quickly, and then you'll have much more success without the overhead of repeatedly loading and reading files (even if you did it in a rolling fashion).

Comment: @Steven, @JB: No, there is no threading involved, so no GIL issues

Comment: @Craig: Can you describe some of the statistics you want to gather from the data?

Comment: @Gregg: All the data we have is collected from a third world country. We will be comparing these collected values from each run to a distribution from a similar run collected from a developed country. We will be running the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare distributions (and maybe the c2 test too)

Comment: @Craig: Please **update** the question to fully specify what you're doing.   Please do not add comments.  Please do not make a complex question **more** complex by adding comments.  Please **update** the question to clarify and respond to the various comments.  Please, please, please.  **update** the question.

Comment: @Craig - updated. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Craig: Dont add comments.  Don't -- in particular -- add apologies.  Fix the question.  The "read the first i average-ages of all files (put them into a list or something" Should be written as some kind of proper Python, not a vague English-language note.  Please **update** the question to be **specific**.  We really are not at all familiar with what you're talking about.  If you can't be **specific** we can't really help you very much.

Comment: @Craig: This takes two SQL queries: one to create the table, one to load the data. It doesnt get easier than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take a simple approach:

- Open each file sequentially and read its lines to fill an in-memory data structure
- Perform statistics on the in-memory data structure

Here is a self-contained example with 3 "files", each containing 3 lines. It uses `StringIO` for convenience instead of actual files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from StringIO import StringIO

# for this example, each "file" has 3 lines instead of 100000
f1 = '1\t10\n2\t11\n3\t12'
f2 = '1\t13\n2\t14\n3\t15'
f3 = '1\t16\n2\t17\n3\t18'

files = [f1, f2, f3]

# data is a list of dictionaries mapping population to average age
# i.e. data[0][10000] contains the average age in location 0 (files[0]) with
# population of 10000.
data = []

for i,filename in enumerate(files):
    f = StringIO(filename)
    # f = open(filename, 'r')
    data.append(dict())

    for line in f:
        population, average_age = (int(s) for s in line.split('\t'))
        data[i][population] = average_age

print data

# gather custom statistics on the data

# i.e. here's how to calculate the average age across all locations where
# population is 2:
num_locations = len(data)
pop2_avg = sum((data[loc][2] for loc in xrange(num_locations)))/num_locations
print 'Average age with population 2 is', pop2_avg, 'years old'
```

The output is:

```
[{1: 10, 2: 11, 3: 12}, {1: 13, 2: 14, 3: 15}, {1: 16, 2: 17, 3: 18}]
Average age with population 2 is 14 years old
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it would be possible to hold 10,000,000 lines in memory.

Make a dictionary where the keys are `number of people` and values are lists of `average age` where each element of the list comes a different file. Therefore, if there are 100 files, each of your lists will have 100 elements.

This way, you don't need to store the file objects in a `dict`

Hope this helps

Comment: It sounds like a lot of data but really - it's not.  Given that the numbers you're storing are just going to be integers, you're going to be looking at a few 10s of megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

I ... don't know if I like this approach, but it's possible that it could work for you.  It has the potential to consume large amounts of memory, but may do what you need it to.  I make the assumption that your data files are numbered.  If that's not the case this may need adaptation.

```
# open the files.
handles = [open('file-%d.txt' % i) for i in range(1, 101)]

# loop for the number of lines.
for line in range(100000):
  lines = [fh.readline() for fh in handles]

  # Some sort of processing for the list of lines.
```

That may get close to what you need, but again, I don't know that I like it.  If you have any files that don't have the same number of lines this could run into trouble.

Comment: Yes, the files have different numbers of lines. This happened because the random walk fizzled out in some runs

Comment: @Craig - I just ran a quick test and it looks like readline() will return a blank string when it's reached the end of the file.  That would make testing in you processing easy, and doesn't look like it would throw an exception.